# When attaching a file to an email, does it need to be stored on the server first?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that automatically exports a table into a CSV file, then I try to attach that same file into a function that will email it. I have sent attachments using html mime mail before, but I was wondering if that created CSV file needs to be stored on the server first before attaching it to the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your functions, if you have a function that can export the table as CSV into a string and then the mail functions support creating attachments from a string then I think you have what you need...

Comment: I just read up on html mime mail and it did mention it can attach files from php strings.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could embed it yourself by writing the appropriate tags and handcrafing the email yourself.

Or you can go the easy way and save it to a temporary location, use a tool like PHPMailer (which might also support string attachment) to attach the file, send the mail and then remove the temp file.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a binary to an email it converts the binary to text so it can be transmitted via a text medium.  A conversion process call `uuencode` is used to convert the binary.

So when you attach a file using a client, it just uuencodes it and adds the text in with the rest of the message.  I am not sure on the exact format to get it to look like an attachment for the client though (rather than just gibberish in the body of the message).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Mail_Mime package from PEAR and its "addAttachment" method, set the "$isfile" (4th) argument to false and pass the string as the "$file" (1st) argument. More [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.addattachment.php).

If you use PHPMailer, use its "AddStringAttachment" method.

If you don't use those then you need to be more specific.